# After opencart migration old url shows in web

Tags: php, html, xampp, migration, opencart

After migration from xampp to normal host. Old url shows in browser when in file are new one. And if in browser manualy you change domain from localhost to new one all works.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC7fL.png)
Also config files are good and it looks everything else works fine

```html
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://mydomain/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://mydomain/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://mydomain/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://mydomain/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/name/public_html/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/name/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/name/public_html/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/name/public_html/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/name/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/name/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/name/public_html/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/name/public_html/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/name/public_html/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/name/public_html/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/name/public_html/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/name/public_html/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'name');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'name_opencartas');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the path inside your `SITE_PATH/config.php` and `SITE_PATH/admin/config.php`

Comment: both of files changed

Comment: the point i was already made this in migration progress. If SITE_PATH/config.php and SITE_PATH/admin/config.php would not be rewrited when site would not work. Now web site works in browser just shows old url in places where should show new one. First i thinked that i forgot change for real in file localhost but when i see that file public_html\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl url is changed in to new one, but brower shows old even on another computer.